# Is there a way to place a sign post?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civ-4 you could place a sign post on the terrain.

I would place a sign post to say that a city was my naval building base.

Can you do this in Civ-5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do that in unmodded Civilization V. Additionally, I don't know of any mod which can enable something like this.

You can rename your cities, though, which might be a good idea to solve your problem; e.g. rename your city to be called "Naval Base".

Comment: or something more creative like "Newport News"